# How to split string into parameters in bash?

Tags: bash

For example, I want to run `find` but the parameter is stored in a varibile.

```
a='-name "build.sh"'
find . $a
```

It shows error: `find: -name "build.sh": unknown primary or operator`

I hope it runs like `find . -name "build.sh"`, how to put the var as parameter`?

Thank you.

Comment: Use shell array: `a=("-name" "build.sh"); find . "${a[@]}"`

Comment: Written like this, your command would try to find a file which name is `"build.sh"`, *including quotes*. It's not the expected behaviour, but it should not give you any error. Are you sure you didn't add a special character in your command, like a non-breakable space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw your code into a file and then use [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) on it, and it will lead you to this page:

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2089

> Quotes/backslashes will be treated literally. Use an array.

Do it this way, instead:

```
a=(-name "build.sh")
find . "${a[@]}"
```